# How to force Selenium Webdriver to use a specific profile

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webautomation

I have seen this question asked in different ways but none of the answers provided will fix my problem.

I am trying to automate a Firefox plugin installation.

1) I have used Java Selenium and AutoIT and it logs into a web application.

2) After clicking on the proper links it will install the plugin.

3) Once the plugin is installed I noticed that it is installed into an anonymous profile instead of "MyProfile" the one I  manually created and had my code initiating it using webdriver (see code snippet below on what was used.)

4) This poses a problem because I have more other Java Selenium AutoIT tests that rely on using "MyProfile" with the plugin installed in that profile and not "Anonymousxxxxx.profile".

5) I cannot have it install into a new anonymous profile each time the test is run. I need it to install into 1 profile each time.

Has anyone came up with a solution to this problem?
This would seem to be a common web application type of test, surely someone was able to overcome this problem.

Here is the code I have already used in hopes of having webdriver use the proper profile. Unfortunately, it appears that it just grabs all the plugins and extensions from that profile and loads it into its own "anonymous" profile.

```
ProfilesIni allProfiles = new ProfilesIni();
      FirefoxProfile profile = allProfiles.getProfile("MyProfile");
      driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Comment: well, doesn't that defeat the purpose of automated testing.

1) I develop a new firefox plugin.

2) I kick off a automated testing that automatically install the plugin and test it.

3) I make code changes and have re kick off testing.

Why would I want to save my profile with an older plugin (old code)?

Comment: If you're using AutoIt you might as well automate the installation process using that. Maybe there's a way to prevent WebDriver from handling profiles this way, but I am not aware of any.

Comment: thanks, after further research it looks like there is no answer to this problem. Selenium is just working by design creating those anonymous profiles. I will have to think of another solution. (code around this crap.)